# AppCompat Toolbar: set toolbar theme from upper theme

Tags: android, android-appcompat, material-design, android-theme, android-toolbar

I have a "light"-themed application with:

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <!-- etc. -->
</style>
```

I want my `Toolbar`s to be dark themed, so I have setup the following style, just as suggested by [Chris Banes](https://chris.banes.me/2014/11/12/theme-vs-style/):

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme.Toolbar" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <!-- stuff -->
</style>
```

Then, by adding `android:theme="@style/Theme.ByodTheme.Toolbar"` to my `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`, everything works as expected (even though the Android Studio preview doesn't show white colors for the title, it works on devices):

[image: Regular application of theme]

Now, instead of specifying `android:theme` for every Toolbar in my application, I'd like to specify the style in my main theme and forget about it. I have tried the `toolbarStyle` property, but it looks like it doesn't work as intended, since it completely messes up standard properties:

[image: Attempt with toolbarStyle]

I have also made other attempts by making the Toolbar theme inherit from `Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar`, and by changing `titleTextAppearance` and `subtitleTextAppearance`, but then it looks impossible to change the overflow icon color (yes, I have tried to set `actionOverflowButtonStyle` and inherit that style from `Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.Overflow`, with no success in changing the overflow icon color).

Is there a way to specify, from a single point, the main theme for every toolbar in my application?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a custom attribute for this -- basically just set your toolbars to use a custom value that you'll define in the theme.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="?attr/toolbar_theme"
    />
```

The important part there is just `android:theme="?attr/toolbar_theme"` which references a custom attribute from the current theme.

You will need to declare this attribute somewhere, like so:

```
<resources>
    <attr name="toolbar_theme" format="reference" />
</resources>
```

Then you can define what value you want the toolbar to use by assigning a value to `toolbar_theme` in your theme. For example, to make it use `Theme.MyTheme.Toolbar` you could define it like so:

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <!-- etc. -->
    <item name="toolbar_theme">@style/Theme.MyTheme.Toolbar</item>
</style>
```

The nice thing about using an attribute is that it lets your app have multiple themes, and that single toolbar resource will use whatever value you've set within the theme.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to set your app's theme once and apply all the styling to all the Toolbars in every activity/fragment.

If so, I would recommend this approach:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/MyColorPrimaryText</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/MyColorWindowBackground</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/MyColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/MyColorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/MyColorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/MyColorControlNormal</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/MyColorControlHighlight</item>
    <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/MyToolbar</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="actionModeBackground">@color/MyColorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>

<style name="MyToolbar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">@dimen/MyToolbarMinHeight</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/MyColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:elevation" tools:ignore="NewApi">10dp</item>
    <item name="theme">@style/MyToolbarTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="MyToolbarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/MyColorPrimaryText</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/MyToolbarColorControlNormal</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/MyToolbarColorControlHighlight</item>
</style>
```

Then in your manifest:

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApp"
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MyActivity1"/>
    <activity android:name=".MyActivity2"/>
</application>
```

Then in your activity layout files, include the toolbar with:

```
style="?attr/toolbarStyle"
```

So myActivity1.xml layout file would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
     android:id="@+id/appBar"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     style="?attr/toolbarStyle" />

<!-- ETC. -->

</LinearLayout>
```

And notice that to change the navigation back button color or the overflow button colors, you can set:

```
<item name="colorControlNormal">@color/MyColorControlNormal</item>
<item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/MyColorControlHighlight</item>
```

And:

```
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/MyColorPrimaryText</item>
```

Can be used to update the actionbar text color but you'd define it in the Toolbar theme.

Hope this helps.